# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined no matter what i tried

Tags: angular, angular7

I keep getting the undefined error no matter what I tried. I do have value when I `console.log(this.EmployeeDetails.gallery);`, `gallery[i].path` does have a value, but my browser console keep prompting it, I tried different methods like setting an empty string first, moving the for-loop in another function and set it await, everything doesn't work.

```
await this.employeeService.getEmployeeDetails(this.Employeeuuid).subscribe((res) => {
  this.EmployeeDetails = res as Employee[];
  this.data.serviceprice = this.EmployeeDetails.serviceprice;
  this.setEmployees();
  console.log(this.EmployeeDetails.gallery);

  for (let i = 0; i <= this.EmployeeDetails.gallery.length; i++) {
    this.photossrc = this.EmployeeDetails.gallery[i].path;
    const src = this.photossrc;
    const caption = 'Image ' + i + ' caption here';
    const thumb = this.EmployeeDetails.gallery[i].path;
    const album = {
      src: src,
      caption: caption,
      thumb: thumb
    };
    this.albums.push(album);
  }
});
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
>       at EmployeeEditComponent.push../src/app/pages/employee/employee-edit/employee-edit.component.ts.EmployeeEditComponent.loadPhotosAndVideos
>   (employee-edit.component.ts:201)
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (employee-edit.component.ts:96)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:134)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next
>   (Subscriber.js:77)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
>   (map.js:41)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next
>   (filter.js:38)
>       at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)

Comment: what is the value inside gallery[i]

Comment: The problem is inside this.EmployeeDetails.gallery[i].
Firstly, check the this.EmployeeDetails.gallery. Maybe it is not array at all or empty array

Comment: Are you sure `  this.EmployeeDetails = res as Employee[];` is correct? You are setting the EmployeeDetails to an array of Employees, not as a single Employee. So you are asking the path of the gallery of an array of employees, not the path of the gallery of an employee.

Comment: You are starting a for loop with index 0 to the length of your list and equal? The time it reaches the length  of your array it will target an unidentified object of your Array. It  should be for (let i = 0; i < this.EmployeeDetails.gallery.length; i++)  your last element index is  this.EmployeeDetails.gallery.length - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop should not be smaller than or equal to the length just smaller, like this:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.EmployeeDetails.gallery.length; i++) {
     ...
    }
```